# Use Term Store as a Filter Webpart

Tags: term-store, filter

I have a couple of libraries that share a term store field for Clients.  I put two list views on a page and planned on using the term store navigator to filter the lists, but couldn't find it in the filter section or any of the other available web part categories.  Is it not available?  Seems strange to not have access to it outside of a regular library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm it doesn't look like taxonomy field made it to filter web parts. I think its called an ISV opportunity ;-)

Maybe its somehow related to my question:
[Taxonomy field doesnt always show up in CQWP filter](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4416/taxonomy-field-doesnt-always-show-up-in-cqwp-filter)

Comment: I didn't want to use a CQWP, but that may be an option.  In my case both have a content type with a shared term store field.