# Taxonomy field doesnt always show up in CQWP filter

Tags: content-query-web-part, managed-metadata, taxonomy

I am using two new features in CQWP to list "related items" in a web part:

Taxonomy field filtering is used to match the current pages taxonomy value given dynamically by [PageFieldValue:MyTaxonomyField].

This works like a charm, as long as i point out a specific list as source:

Soruce: /news/pages
Content type: My News CT
Additional filters: 
    MyTaxonomyField > contains any of > Custom Value or Query:[PageFieldValue:MyTaxonomyField]

Now thats pretty damn neat, but I want the source to be from all pages using that content type, but if i select site and subsites as source > list type: Pages library > and select same content type as before, the filter list doesnt contain my taxonomy filter!

Have anyone got a good explanation on this?

I havent tried editing the webpart xml directly, but thats my next move anyway (since i want to wrap it up in a feature).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have more than one CQWP on the page when testing.

We keep source at the top level and use CAML in the Query Override. ContentTypeId Begins With and use the Parent Content Type ID + 00 + Hexadecimal GUID for the Value. Define the Path Equals /news/pages and any parameters around dates that you want.

That being said, we've found that using Highlight = 1 is way easier but still, top level source and define the path in the Query Override may get you going down the right path.

Our scenario is surfacing Recent News on a Publishing Site with Approval Workflow.

Comment: thanx for the answer. It didnt make any difference if there were one or many CQWP on the page. In the end i wiped my SC and tried re-adding content types and site columns. This in the end worked, never did find out what borked the site to behave like this :-S

Answer (score 1):

In the end i wiped my SC and tried re-adding content types and site columns. This worked, never did find out what borked the site to behave like this :-S

Answer (score 1):

### Support for usage taxonomy fields (multiple values) for filtering in CQWP

In case of usage **multi** value taxonomy fields for filtering, it could be specified in web part editor when **target list** is selected only (Source property = *Show items from the following List*)

For another sources (*Show items from all sites in this site collection* or *Show items from the following site and all subsites*) filtering based on multiple values taxonomy fields **could not be specified using web part editor**, but could be specified explicitly using web part properties (filter operator, filter type and filter value)

> Internally CQWP web part editor generates available fields for
>   filtering based on *source* and *field type*. For **multi** value taxonomy fields, when source *Show items from all sites in this site collection* or *Show items from the following site and all subsites* is selected, they are excluded from available fields for filtering

---

The *filter operator*, *filter type* and *filter value* properties should be specified for filtering based on multiple taxonomy field, for example:

[FilterOperator1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.filteroperator1.aspx)

Specify [filter operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.filterfieldqueryoperator)

```
<property name="FilterOperator1" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart+FilterFieldQueryOperator, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">ContainsAny</property>
```

[FilterType1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.filtertype1.aspx)

To specify multiple taxonomy field:

```
<property name="FilterType1" type="string">TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti</property>
```

[FilterValue1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.filtervalue1.aspx)

Specify taxonomy field internal name:

```
<property name="FilterField1" type="string">[PageFieldValue:MyTaxonomyField]</property>
```